# Saving entities are taking very long time to save into DB, How can we speed up?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm consuming a large amount of data from an external API, which has around 150,000 rows, which contains a lot of text in some of the fields. I'm able to construct the entities by the data consumed with 5-10 seconds of time (max 15 seconds), but saving these entities is taking around 20-30 minutes.
I want to speed this up, how can I make it better?

**Note:** It's a single table and entity, not having any children

**Dev Stacks:** MySQL, Hibernate, Spring Data JPA and Java 11

**Observations:**

- When breakpoints are enabled, saving takes more time.
  Without breakpoint saving time takes around 15-20 minutes, with breakpoint saving time takes around 20-30 minutes
- Memory and CPU utilization is normal 40-50% utilization including other applications running

Please suggest some solution or an idea.

Comment: Hi, this question is not duplicate as suggested in the duplicate section, That is basically talking about taking the file data and saving as one entity to DB, Whereas here consuming lot of data via API, and saving multiple entities.

Comment: Try batch inserts and see, Spring Batch may be